# How do I fix RichEmbed?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to print get embed message in discord, but this happens:

> TypeError: Discord.RichEmbed is not a constructor

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'mytokenhere';
const prefix = '!';

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('This bot is online!');
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]) {
        case 'pomoc':
            message.channel.send('.')
            break;
        case 'cc':
            if(!args[1]) return message.reply('Podaj 2 argument! (liczbe wiadomosci do skasowania)')
            message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]); 
            break;
        case 'embed':
            var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setAuthor(message.author.username)
                .setDescription("Usuario rikolino.")
                .setColor("#3535353")
                .addField("Usuario", '${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}')
                .addField("ID", message.author.id)
                .addField("Creación", message.author.createdAt);

            message.channel.send({embed});
            break;
    }
});

bot.login(token);
```

I tried many other solutions, but the result is always the same, I really don't know where the problem is.

Comment: It looks like you should use `Discord.MessageEmbed` instead: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-richembedmessageembed-constructor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Discord.js

discord.js have update `new Discord.MessageEmbed()` from `new Discord.RichEmbed()`

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(message.author.username)
    .setDescription("Usuario rikolino.")
    .setColor("#3535353")
    .addField("Usuario", '${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}')
    .addField("ID", message.author.id)
    .addField("Creación", message.author.createdAt);

message.channel.send(embed);
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Edric said, use `MessageEmbed` instead:

```js
var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(message.author.username)
    .setDescription("Usuario rikolino.")
    .setColor("#3535353")
    .addField("Usuario", '${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}')
    .addField("ID", message.author.id)
    .addField("Creación", message.author.createdAt);

message.channel.send(embed);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's been renamed to `MessageEmbed` in v12.

If you don't want to replace all of your existing code, you can use this workaround:

```
const { MessageEmbed: RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");

let embed = new RichEmbed().setTitle("Works the same");
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you used `RichEmbed();`
use `MessageEmbed();` instead